# How to skip the sonarqube cognitive complexity for the parent function?

Tags: sonarqube, code-complexity

My angularjs controller file always starts with two nested function definitions. Like,

```
define(['dependencies'], function(appName) {
  appName.controler('controllerName', [function main($scope) {

    /* actual code here*/
    $scope.method1 = function() {/*code*/}
    $scope.method2 = function() {/*code*/}
    ...

  }]);
})
```

I need to calculate the cognitive complexity only for the method1 & method2, etc that are inside the #main function. And **skip for the #main function (parent function)** as which complexity will be the sum of all its child methods complexity. And which always more than the threshold >15.

Comment: Maybe [NOSONAR](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/faq/#FrequentlyAskedQuestions-HowtoremoveFalse-Positiveissues?) can help you.

Comment: Thanks, Jeroen Heier. I was looking for this only.